# Absolutely positioned elements don't show a margin-left effect

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="map1" style=" float: left; margin-left: 150px; border:2px solid grey;">
<div id="red">                            
<div id="green"></div>                            
<img id="map_img" src="images/map/location-map-small.gif" alt="map">
</div>
</div>  
#map1{
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 100px;
width : 400px;
height : 400px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 105;

}
#green{
background: url("location-map-large.gif");
background-position: 0px 0px;
background-color: green;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
display : none;
border: 2px solid grey;    
}
#red{
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
}
```

I have two divs showing the zooming effect styled as listed below. The problem is that there isn't any effect of adding "margin-left" style to the "map1" element, what should I do to place it according to my requirement?

Comment: Use `left` instead of `margin-left`

Answer (score 2):

Add 'position:relative' to map1 CSS and then use the left property to position green and red.

```
#map1 {
    background: blue;
    width : 400px;
    height : 400px;
    position: relative;
}

#green {
    background: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
}
```

See result here:
http://jsfiddle.net/u4j2F/

Comment: thnx, but i would like to move the div#map1 not the image inside it

Comment: your fiddle worked correctly but on my page it is still not moving :( . what shoul i do?

Comment: you haven't used my full code. can you use the full code and show me the demo. for example in my code green is inside red and red is inside map1.

Comment: map1 is the main block and the margin is already working (the one in the HTML overrides the one in the CSS: `style="margin-left;"`. Moreover in your code map1 is not positioned absolutely. Can you describe exactly what you want at the end?

Comment: ok i got it solved. if you are qurious enough i can try to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

you can position the element width padding

[Live Demo here](http://jsbin.com/folec/12/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: thnx, but i would like to move the div#map1 not the image inside it.

Comment: @buet_baba can you post a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: ok i got it solved. if you are qurious enough i will upload one.

Answer (score 0):

this for my successors. :) in this case i used   `positioning : relative`  for the id "map1" and used left instead of margin-left and got my job done.